# Show any type of file saved in a model to a container div in the template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

Hi am working on django

I would like to show a  file which is saved in the django model into a div in the django template.The file can be any format like .txt, .html, .png, .gif etc...

my model look like this

```
class RepositoryFiles(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('file', 'name'),)
```

In my view i do the basic filtering operations

```
RepositoryFiles.objects.all()
```

In my template , now I give the file url to an anchor tag which will open it

```
{% for file in files %}
<div class="col-sm-2" style="
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    ">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: center;">
        <a target="_self" href="{{ file.file.url }}" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
        <span class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 10px 0px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{ file.name }}">{{ file.name }}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to open it in a div inside the current template on clicking the link

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show me what have you implemented in your views & templates

Comment: I have been modified the question, you can see the changes

Comment: What is the error that you getting? or when you click the button whats happening?

Comment: There is no error now.I would like to modify the click event so that instead of opening the file in the new tab, open it in a <div> inside the HTML code.